# Canadian traveling to Europe and Japan wanting to "reset the clock"

Tags: visas, schengen, japan, overstaying

I am about to overstay in Europe on my Canadian passport for the purpose of tourism. I also recently spent three months in Japan.

Question: does a re-entry into the EU/Japan reset the 90 days clock?

I've done some research saying that EU is rolling 90 days and no clocks can be reset.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the Schengen 90/180 rule work?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/how-does-the-schengen-90-180-rule-work) And see this related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13482/what-are-the-consequences-of-a-us-citizen-overstaying-a-schengen-visa

Comment: Do not overstay in the Schengen area ! See the above links

Comment: Note that far from all of Europe is Schengen, so you can visit other parts of Europe while waiting out your Schengen limit.

Answer (score 2):

Schengen is "90 days out of 180 days".  So it's a sliding window.  If you are up on day 90, then your "past 180 day" window is completely full, and will remain full for another 90 days, when days will start scrolling off the end.

Note too that entering an EU nation isn't a *right* (that would be citizenship).  If your facts do not impress your entry officer that your true purpose is tourism, they may refuse your re-entry even if you get the day thing correct.

Comment: Please quote your source for 'Poland has a "180 days limit"'. There is an [Aggreement of 1991-04-15](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/152435/95267) for US Nationals for 90 days or less, but that has nothing to do with a **180 days  limit** and is not for Canadians.

Comment: See also: [List of Member States' bilateral visa waiver agreements with third countries allowing for an extension of the period of stay in accordance with Article 20(2), point (b), of the Convention implementing the Schengen Agreement - Publications Office of the EU](https://op.europa.eu/en/publication-detail/-/publication/c067e92d-5a8b-11e9-9151-01aa75ed71a1), where for Poland the agreement of 1991-04-15 with the US is **not** meantioned. Only 7 South/ Central American states for 90 days are listed.

Comment: There is no "90 days out of 180 days" EU limit. The limit you are referring to is for the Schengen area. There are several EU countries, which are not in the Schengen area and in which you can stay without the Schengen clock counting and there there several non-EU countries in the Schengen area, in which the clock is counting when you are staying.

Comment: @Tor Oh you're quite right, thank you.

Comment: @MarkJohnson *I could swear that was a thing* and it was repeatedly discussed right here on StackExchange.  But I can't find references to it now. Paragraph deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Europe is not a country and there are no common immigration rules for all EU countries. If you move around a bit, it should be no problem for a Canadian citizen to stay indefinitely in Europe without breaking any immigration rules. You do have to move around a bit though.

The rules you are referring to (rolling 90 out of 180 days) are for the Schengen area. If you have stayed in the Schengen area for 90 days, you can't just leave and reenter to reset the clock.

There are however still a few EU countries, which are not part of the Schengen area (Ireland, Bulgaria, Romania and Cyprus), in which you can also stay without the Schengen clock ticking. Bulgaria, Romania and Cyprus have the same 90 out of 180 days rolling window as in the Schengen area, but the clock is ticking independently for each country. I am not 100% sure about Ireland, but I believe you can stay there for 3 months as a tourist and that leaving and reentering will indeed reset the clock.

Then there are also a few non-EU countries, which are members of the Schengen area, e.g. Norway, Iceland, Switzerland, in which your stay is counting on your Schengen clock.

And at last, still plenty of European countries, which are neither in the EU nor in the Schengen area, between which you can move around and be granted a separate period of stay for each entry. You can as a Canadian citizen enter most other European countries without a visa.