# Can two passports extend 90 day rule in Bulgaria (EU but not Schengen)?

Tags: passports

Just like the headline asks, can I stay in Bulgaria for 90 days, then exit on the passport I entered on?  Then enter on another passport on day 92 on another passport?

1 is US, 1 is Guatemala

Comment: Question has been asked a dozen times, and the answer is always no. The rule applies to a person, not a passport.

Comment: I thought it might depend on the countries involved. That's why I asked. For instance, US citizens can stay 180 consecutive days in Hungary without violating their EU/Schengen laws--as long as US citizen exits and enters EU through Hungary in the 2d 90 days. I can talk more about Spain/Guatemala laws too. So it's not a stupid question as your answer seems to imply.

Comment: "US citizens can stay 180 consecutive days in Hungary without violating their EU/Schengen laws": but not because of having two passports.  Also I am not sure how it works with Hungary, but with Poland at least there is a bilateral agreement allowing 3 months' stay even when the Schengen days are exhausted.  But if the Schengen days are not exhausted, both clocks are ticking at once.  As a consequence, a US citizen can spend 90 days in Germany (or wherever) and then three months in Poland, but not 180 says in Poland.  I suppose Hungary treats its bilateral agreements the same, but I don't know.

Comment: Related question for Schengen area: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/24087/could-a-citizen-of-two-countries-eligible-for-90-180-schengen-stays-legally-rema

Comment: @CMA With Hungary, there is the aggreement of 1991-11-01 for an Authorised length of stay: 90 days. See [List of Member States' bilateral visa waiver agreements with third countries allowing for an extension of the period of stay in accordance with Article 20(2), point (b), of the Convention implementing the Schengen Agreement - Publications Office of the EU](https://op.europa.eu/en/publication-detail/-/publication/c067e92d-5a8b-11e9-9151-01aa75ed71a1)

Comment: @phoog There is a 'letter of understanding' of 1991-04-15 between Poland and the US State Department that **only** states that US citizens no longer require a visa for stays of 90 days or less.  **Nothing more than that** is stated in this 'aggreement' that has been quoted elsewhere as the source of the 'bilateral agreement allowing 3 months'. This letter is **not** listed in the bilateral visa waiver agreements list published by the EU.

Comment: A valid link to the 'letter of understanding' and a image of the relevant line can be found at the accepted answer of [US Citizen in Poland more than 90 days in a 180 day period](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/57537/95267)

Answer (score 7):

It's not legal, but if they only enforce the duration of stay with passport stamps, or if they have an entry/exit database that can't match your two passports to the same person for some reason, you may be able to get away with it.  It's pretty risky, though.  If you are caught, you could suffer some fairly serious consequences, likely including not being able to go to Bulgaria for at least a few years (I don't know whether this would affect your ability to enter the Schengen area; Bulgaria isn't yet territorially part of the area, but it has joined the Schengen *acquis* so it participates in various Schengen institutions).

If you want to stay in Bulgaria for 180 days it's probably better to find a way to get a type D visa that will allow you to do so legally.

Comment: My basic assumption is that overstaying in any country will get you banned from all countries (except your own). Not all of Bulgaria, or all Schengen countries, but **all countries**.

Comment: @user253751 do you base that assumption on anything in particular?  If you look for example at US immigration law ([8 USC 1182(a)(9)(B)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1182#a_9_B), it bans people for 3 or 10 years for being unlawfully present in the United States, but only under certain conditions, and only if they meet those conditions for at least 181 days (3-year ban) or a year (10-year ban).  There is nothing about overstaying in other countries. That can make it difficult to convince a visa officer to grant a visa, but that's not a ban.

Comment: because it's a lot more sensible to assume this than to assume you will not be banned from a country.

Comment: @user253751 does that mean that if you ever overstay anywhere you will never again seek to travel internationally?

Comment: it means I will never expect to be accepted to travel internationally, and plan accordingly